# JavaScriptのテンプレートリテラルのメリット

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

文字列を連結する方法で、「＋」を用いる

```
console.log("名前は"　+　name　+　"です")
```

ではなく、テンプレートリテラルの

```
console.log(`名前は${name}です`)
```

を用いるメリットは、視認性の向上のみなのでしょうか？

文字列連結を行う際に、毎度どちらを使用するか迷ってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

視認性向上のみで、テンプレートリテラル使えばよいと思います。
ESLint の fix オプションで自動変換もしてくれますよ。

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Answer (score 0):

一つの利点として文字列内に`"`または`'`が現れる場合でもエスケープ不要ということがありますね。逆に`` ` ``はエスケープする必要がありますけどそっちはそんなに使うものではないので。